# How to prove $ \neg (A \wedge B) \Leftrightarrow \neg A \vee \neg B$

Tags: logic

I see this exise on Zorich's mathematical analysis. Obviously, I can't prove it without foundation. When I write this question in this web , I saw likely question, them prove some likely question in Hilbert system. But I fail prove it in Hilbert system. How to show it ? Besides, for  analysis, which system is conventional ?

Comment: I know that there are some logic systems where this is the _definition_ of either $\lor$ or $\land$. I don't know how that is for Hilbert's system.

Comment: See De Morgan's laws. Zorich defines the logical operators with truth tables; thus, the only way is to use them to check the equivalence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that 
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 A & B &(A \wedge B)  &  \neg (A \wedge B)
\\\hline
 V & V & V  &  F
\\\hline
 V & F & F  &  V
\\\hline
 F & V & F  &  V
\\\hline
 F & F & F  &  V
\\\hline
\end{array}
$$
and 
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 A & B & \neg A  &  \neg B & \neg A \vee \neg B 
\\\hline
 V & V & F  &  F & F 
\\\hline
 V & F & F  &  V & V 
\\\hline
 F & V & V  &  F & V 
\\\hline
 F & F & V  &  V & V 
\\\hline
\end{array}
$$